# Is it possible to clear out an Append Only Comment field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, append-changes

I have an Append Only Comments field which works great on my SharePoint Document Library.  The customer uses it to record comments during a document's review cycle.  Recently, the customer has asked if this field can be periodically cleared out so that it is fresh; that is, they want to only see comments for the most recent review cycle.

Is it possible to completely clear out the comments in this Append-Only comments field, so that it starts anew?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to list settings->Versioning  settings->select "No" for "Create a version each time you edit an item in this list"

Or you can navigate to list settings->click on the column, select "No" for "Append Changes to Existing Text".